# Fail2ban for nginx post flood ignores time intervals

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I'm trying to create a fail2ban filter that is going to ban the host when it sends over 100 POST requests over 30 seconds interval.

jail.local:

```
[nginx-postflood]

enabled = false
filter = nginx-postflood
action = myaction
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
findtime = 30
bantime = 100
maxretry = 100
```

nginx-postflood.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*"POST.*
ignoreregex =
```

Using GREP i was able to test the regular expressions and indeed it matches Host and POST requests.

Problem is that it bans **any Host that performs at least one POST request**. This means likely that it's not taking *findttime* or *maxretry* options into consideration. In my opinion it's timestamp issue.

Sample line of nginx log:

```
5.5.5.5 - user [05/Aug/2014:00:00:09 +0200] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 200 6714 "http://referer.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Any help?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it maybe to late for the answer but anyway...

The excerpt you have posed has the filter disabled.

> enabled = false

As there is not mentioning of Fail2Ban version and syslog/fail2ban logs are missing for this jail.

I tested your Filter on fail2ban 0.9.3-1 and it works fine although I had to enable it and had to drop the line with **action = myaction** as you have not provided what you are expecting fail2ban to do.

Therefore this filter should work fine, based that it's enabled and the action is correct as well.

What is happening in the provided example is that Your Filter is disabled and fail2ban is using another Filter which checks the same log file and matches your regex but has more restrictive rules i.e ban after 1 request.